# Synchronous Until-Successful failure Expression not working

Tags: java, mule

I have a groovy component inside Until-successful block which is throwing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.
In Until-Successful Failure Expression I am declaring expression #[exception.causedBy(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)]

Now ideally it should be True and retries should happen only for this particular Exception but they are happening for every exception also. Even if I manually set failure expression as False by '#[false]' or i set a variable and compare its value with itself( comparing with value different from Variable itself), still it doesn't work.

```
<until-successful maxRetries="5" millisBetweenRetries="600" failureExpression="[exception.causedBy(java.net.SocketTimeoutException)]" doc:name="Until Successful" synchronous="true">
        <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[throw new IllegalArgumentException()]]></scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>
    </until-successful>
```

I just want it to retry for specific exceptions and for other exceptions it should throw exception without retrying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you misunderstand how the Until-Successful scope works with a FailureExpression.

By reading again de documentation [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/until-successful-scope), this scope works as follow :

- By default, the Until-Successful retries if any exception is thrown within it. Thus, if now exception is thrown, no retry is attempted whatever the content of the payload or the header are
- If a FailureExpression is configured, the Until-Successful retries if an exception is thrown OR if the FailureExpression if evaluated to true. Read this :

> failureExpression  : Specifies an expression that, when it evaluated to true, determines that the processing of one route was a failure. If no expression is provided, only an exception will be treated as a processing failure.

In your case, the Until-Successful scope indeed retries since your FailureExpression is evaluated to True. Replacing this expression by #[true] inevitably makes this scope to retry until the Maximum attempts configured is reached.

Hope it helps ;)

/Tony

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tony. Sorry for misunderstanding ... I mean to say that no matter I keep it as True or False, still it is retrying every exception.
So I want to handle specific exception to retry in Until-Successful .. Rest I want to throw directly into Catch block without any retries.

Comment: In this case, I would suggest you put the script block in a separate flow and use a '<flow-ref />' in your until-successful scope. From this flow, you can add an exception strategy dedicated to the former and specify all but a few exceptions to be caught inside. Thus, the until-successful scope will no longer retry for them.